# Can't delete current row of jQuery DataTable using local button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a jQuery Datatable and I dynamically add rows. Each row has a cell in which there's a delete button. My problem is that I can't get to delete the rows with the buttons and I can't even manage to target the current row.

Here's my DataTable code :

```
var tab_presta = $("#tableau_presta").DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "paging":   false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info":     false,
    responsive: true,
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No product added to the contract for the moment."
      }
});
```

Here is how I create the buttons on each row (on a submit event) :

```
form2.on('submit', function (event) {

tab_presta.row.add( 
    [            
        '<center><button type="button" id="btn_supp' + (++idCount) + '" onclick="alert(this.parentNode)" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-danger confirmation">Delete</button></center>'
    ] 
)
.draw( false );

// here I dynamically add an id to each button based on a variable
$('.btn btn-xs btn-block btn-danger confirmation').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'suppr' + idCount);
        idCount++;
    });
});
```

And here is my code for deleting when clicking on each button :

```
for (j = 0; j <= btn_count; j++) {
    $("#tableau_presta").on("click", btn_supp[j], function(){
        //tab_presta.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        console.log(row);
    });
}
```

As you can see I commented the remove() part because it doesn't work, so I tried to find the closest `tr` of `$(this) (button)`, but I don't get the row in the console as a result. It's empty and I don't understand why because the button actually exists and I can get its id when I click on it if I put a `onclick"alert(this.id)`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind the click event inside of a loop. Instead, use a `class` or an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). In this case, selecting all elements with an `id` that `^` starts with `btn_supp` = `[id^=btn_supp]`.

```js
$("#tableau_presta").on("click", "[id^=btn_supp]", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableau_presta">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" id="btn_supp1" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-danger confirmation">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" id="btn_supp2" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-danger confirmation">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Serg, it works !
Though I don't really understand why my loop doesn't work ?

Comment: Assigning an event in a loop is redundant and kind of bad. However, the real problem may have been `btn_supp[j]`. That looks like it should at least be `"#btn_supp"+j`. You're supposed to be providing a css selector.

Comment: I've got another problem now : when I click on the button it deletes the row as asked, but when I add another row dynamically (through another form), it adds the new row AND the rows that I had deleted. I tried to add ".draw(false)" after ".remove()" but it doesn't work. An idea ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataTable plugin, sounds like you're just generating rows from a list. When you delete, you don't delete from the data source so they eventually get readded. Just a guess, this should be a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers @Serg, I found the answer for the other problem. You were right, it's a plugin so I had to follow the plugin's way to do it. Here is my function after editting it as the official website suggests :

tab_presta.on("click", "[id^=btn_supp]", function() {
        tab_presta.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
      });

"tab_presta" is actually : 
var tab_presta = $("#tableau_presta").DataTable({ blabla.. });

Thank you again